# php5-fpm.sock failed

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Был сайт на `VPS` на **DigitalOcean**. Сегодня при заходе на сайт возникает ошибка:

> 502 Bad Gateway

На сервере процессор не загружен, и память свободная есть. Сайт на `wordpress`, `nginx`. Думаю, что необходимо перезапустить nginx. Как бы не накосячить. Что еще можно сделать?

**P.S.** Сегодня долгое время не мог авторизоваться в digitalocean, создал тикет - говорят что с их стороны все норм.

**P.S.S.**
Пример ошибки из лога:

> 2015/12/14 06:27:20 [error] 13245#0: *82206 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 176.209.247.129, server: www.d2battle.club, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "d2battle.club", referrer: "http://d2battle.club/reglament/"

Comment: Посмотри логи `nginx`. В них должна хранится полезная тебе информация.

Comment: Просмотрел логи около 500 ошибок.  
Большинство ошибок такие :  
2015/12/13 07:07:18 [error] 13246#0: *81269 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.166.139.20, server: www.d2battle.club, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "188.166.31.15"

Comment: Добавьте логи в ваш вопрос, а то в комментах они не читаемы.

Comment: Я бы предложил обратиться к DIgitalOcean с твоими логами, но вот [здесь](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/getting-nginx-fpm-sock-error) советуют сделать бекап и переустановить nginx с  php5-fpm.

Comment: А еще добавь в вопрос конфигурацию `nginx`

Comment: Техподдержка посоветовала : 

service php-fpm restart.

Заработало.

Comment: Да, но это только на время решит проблему. И так каждый раз будешь перезапускать? Предлагаю сразу решить эту проблему)

Answer (score 1):

> connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed

судя по этому сообщению, у вас для интерпретации файлов, написанных на *php*, используется сервер *php5-fpm*, и он, видимо, не отвечает.

возможно, «упал» из-за ошибки. смотрите логи. вероятно, это `/var/log/php5-fpm.log`.

для перезапуска сервера *php5-fpm* воспользуйтесь «стандартным» способом:

```
$ sudo service php5-fpm restart
```